# How to create a Oracle global type and use it in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle RECORD TYPE declared in procedure or function is local, therefore it might be used locally only. How to declare a RECORD TYPE that is global and might be used in all procedures and functions globally in DB?

Comment: it is preferable to choose one location to post questions.  This was cross-posted on DBA.SE -- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/how-to-create-a-global-type-and-use-it-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Record` types cannot be created as a separate schema object, so to make a `Record` type publicly available the type is usually declared in a package specification, or a package body to be available only in the scope of that package.

Comment: @centurion :If you want to have a record type ,create an database object type of your record and then create a nested table of your object type .Then you'll be able to use that in your package .

Answer (score 3):

A basic example of using object type in your package .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_rec IS OBJECT
(
 ID             VARCHAR2(30)
 ,TYPE               VARCHAR2(30)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_NT AS TABLE OF test_rec;
/

declare
 v_test_NT   test_NT;

begin
select test_rec (id
                ,type
                 )
        BULK COLLECT INTO v_test_NT  
 FROM test ;

--use it as you want

end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly what I was hoping to find :) because it involves the creation or nested table and traversing through the collection even if there's only one record. When using pl/sql record type you just create a type and use it.

Comment: I am sorry but above example is wrong. you can't use objects in a PACKAGE like this. Well, just compile and see the error. Your example works outside of the package well, but not in the package.

Comment: @Petar: Can you please share ,how your creating package ? because i am not getting any compilation issues